# How to change the target of a file for a multiple file field in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content type with a file field: `field_document`.

It contains multiple files.

I chose `Generic file` as display format in `manage display` setting.

I need to change the `target` attribute of the files that drupal generates for me. How can I do that?

So instead of this

```
OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/file-link.html.twig'
```

```
<span class="file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf">
  <a
    href="http://somedomain.com/sites/default/files/document/2017/test_document_8.pdf"
    type="application/pdf; length=8108"
    title="test_document.pdf">Test Document</a>
</span>
```

I would need this: `target="_blank"`

```
<span class="file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf">
  <a
    href="http://somedomain.com/sites/default/files/document/2017/test_document_8.pdf"
    type="application/pdf; length=8108"
    title="test_document.pdf"
    target="_blank">Test Document</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a hook, but also in a custom file-link template in your theme. Check if the file link has a class specific to a pdf file and then set the target attribute:

*file-link.html.twig*

```
{% if attributes.hasclass('file--application-pdf') %}
  <span{{ attributes.setAttribute('target', '_blank') }}>{{ link }}</span>
{% else %}
  <span{{ attributes }}>{{ link }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

@4k4's snippet actually just applies the attribute to the containing element, not the anchor.

You can override `template_preprocess_file_link()` in your theme and set `$options['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';`.

Related: https://www.drupal.org/node/301234